# How to apply condition for specific page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I want to apply condition for specific page coming from url. It is neither a category page nor a custom cms page. Url is like `localhost/project/index.php/news/blog.html`. I want to apply condition for this `news/blog.html` . News or blog is not a category and not any cms page. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add condition by match string from current Url.

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

 if (preg_match('/news/blog.html/',$currentUrl)){

 }
```

Comment: RouteName is not 'news', i think.
Because when i print $this->getRequest()->getRouteName(); it shows as 'cms' .  @S H Patel

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Please Use below code :

```
    $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
    $path = $url->getPath();

    $blogPaths = 'news/blog.html';

    if(strpos($path,$blogPaths) !== false){
       //do something here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You all might have answered correctly and might have your logic and knowledge to the perfect, but *Module* condition helped me for the case.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'module_name');
{
   condition;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `handler` in your case

For printing handler you can use below code.

```
print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

IN this page you can get unique handler in `array[3]` use that for condition and may be your problem will solve

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get information about you URL

```
localhost/project/index.php/news/blog.html
```

Use following method to get details about ControllerName,ActionName,RouteName

```
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$this->getRequest()->getActionName();
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

if it's CMS page then get Identifier using

```
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()
```

Put Validation base on above methods